# Twitter Bootstrap Popovers not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="disclaimer">After 30 Days you'll have the option to keep your account for $15 per month -no contract required-or revert to a single page free account.*</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#disclaimer').popover({
  trigger: 'hover',
  html: true,
  placement: 'right',
  content: 'hello world'
});
```

When I hover over the element, nothing happens.. no JavaScript errors or anything, not sure whats wrong

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using your exact code, all I had to do to get it to work was wrap it in a function call and put the script below the div tag.  If you placed your jQuery in an onload function it would work just as well.  Good luck.

Use this:

```
<div id="disclaimer" >After 30 Days you'll have the option to keep your account for $15 per month -no contract required-or revert to a single page free account.*</div>

<script>
$(function ()  
{
  $('#disclaimer').popover(
  {
     trigger: 'hover',
     html: true,
     placement: 'right',
     content: 'hello world'
  });
});
</script>
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#disclaimer').popover(
  {
     trigger: 'hover',
     html: true,
     placement: 'right',
     content: 'hello world'
  });
});
```

Comment: I have mine wrapped in a `$(document).ready` and still, nothing happens :(

Comment: Can you put it into the html in the script tag?  If that still doesn't work you might want to check to make sure you have the tooltip included in your [bootstrap.js](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips)

Comment: I figured it out... It was the ActiveAdmin JavaScript conflicting with twitter bootstrap... thanks for your help!

Comment: The answer is found in this comment: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/450#issuecomment-16478422

Comment: I agree, active admin was causing conflicts. I solved it by moving active admin to `vendor/javascripts` directory and it worked

Answer (score 1):

i had been looking for over a day as to why my popover wasn't working after getting autodisabled due to events happening on my page (a complicated app, something that gets enabled/disabled depending on the state of what is going on) and the key was to NOT have it the document ready but to have it out in a function because it gets enabled after document initialization on a button click.

Comment: It seems you cannot clone popovers, which was my issue. Thanks, this tip made me try a different approach. If I apply the popover after cloning, it works.